# Who gets updated first, parents or children? (cocos2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Let's say I have a parent node with N child nodes. They all have scheduled updates on every frame. Whose `update:` selector gets called first, the child nodes or the parent? Is there any set order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visit` method in `CCNode` has the following code:

```
if(children_) {
    ccArray *arrayData = children_->data;
    NSUInteger i = 0;

    // draw children zOrder < 0
    for( ; i < arrayData->num; i++ ) {
        CCNode *child = arrayData->arr[i];
        if ( [child zOrder] < 0 )
            [child visit];
        else
            break;
    }

    // self draw
    [self draw];

    // draw children zOrder >= 0
    for( ; i < arrayData->num; i++ ) {
        CCNode *child =  arrayData->arr[i];
        [child visit];
    }
```

So, as you can see, first are visited children whose `zOrder` is less than zero, then the current node (the children's parent) is drawn, then the rest of children is also visited (note that visiting a node will eventually draw it, according to the criteria just explained).